# What would be a good Test Class for this Apex Class?

Tags: unit-test

I'm looking for the correct syntax to create a Test Class for this component.

```
public class CreateCustomMetadataQuickAppSwitcher implements Metadata.DeployCallback{

    public void handleResult(Metadata.DeployResult result, Metadata.DeployCallbackContext context) {
        if (result.status == Metadata.DeployStatus.Succeeded) {
            System.debug(' success : '+ result);
        } else {
            System.debug(' fail : '+ result);
        }
    }

    @InvocableMethod(label='Create/Update QuickAppSwitcher Custom Metadata Record')
    public static void createCustomMetadata(List<String> flowParameters) {
        List<String> parameterCollection = new List<String>();
        parameterCollection = flowParameters[0].split('~');
        Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
        customMetadata.fullName = parameterCollection[0];
        customMetadata.label = parameterCollection[1];

            Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField1 = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
            customField1.field = 'AppAPINames__c';
            customField1.value = parameterCollection[2]; 
            customMetadata.values.add(customField1);

            Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField2 = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
            customField2.field = 'AppImageNames__c';
            customField2.value = parameterCollection[3]; 
            customMetadata.values.add(customField2);

            Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField3 = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
            customField3.field = 'AppAlternateTexts__c';
            customField3.value = parameterCollection[4]; 
            customMetadata.values.add(customField3);

        Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
        mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);
        CreateCustomMetadataQuickAppSwitcher callback = new CreateCustomMetadataQuickAppSwitcher();
        Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, callback);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Trailhead module on [Testing Your Metadata Deployment](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_metadata_api/apex_metadata_api_testing).

To sum up, metadata deploys won't actually execute in unit test context (that would result in unit tests have side effects that violate test context isolation).

You can test your callback by calling it directly with synthesized parameters.

As for the deployment code, your only real route is to verify that it creates the right metadata for deployment (since you cannot verify the deployment itself). To do so here, you would need to factor your `@InvocableMethod` to put the logic to create the deployment container into a separate method so that you can call it in test context. You can then inspect its contents and validate them, as depicted in Trailhead.

Your current implementation doesn't allow you to write assertions against the contents of your deployment container because it's never exposed outside the invocable method.

Comment: When I try the suggestions in the Trailhead I get "Invalid type: DeployMetadata" and "Invalid type: PostInstallCallback" errors.

Comment: @EricSmith You will not be able to copy and paste the code from Trailhead. You'll need to apply the principles it is trying to explain to your own code, which has entirely different types and structure.

Comment: Ahh, I just realized that